# How to create a dialog result in maham?

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to create a code to show a dialog result:

```
var result = this.ShowMessageAsync("proceed?", "Info", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
if (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

but the compiler on this line `if (result == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)`, show me this message:

> you can not apply the == operator to operands of type 'Task ' and 'MessageDialogResult'

In some example it was used this operator, what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowMessageAsync()` seems to be an asyncronous method, meaning it returns a `Task<T>` instead of a `T`.

So you can either `await` the task like this:

```
var result = await this.ShowMessageAsync("proceed?", "Info", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative);
```

Or you can get the `Result` of it:

```
var result = this.ShowMessageAsync("proceed?", "Info", MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative)
    .Result;
```

Not that if you want to `await` the task, you must be in a method marked `async`